# How to fix CMake file provided by the OpenGL Superbible 6th edition book

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, cmake, glfw

I'm having problems compiling the example code provided with the [OpenGL Superbible, 6th ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321902947). I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 and CMake 3.13.4. I have all the necessary dependencies. CMake executes with no problems ("cmake ."), but when I enter the make command it fails.

I'm under the impression it has to do with GLFW but I don't know how to change CMake for it to work.

Here's a link to the example code.
https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code

I've already fixed the issue in line 13 of the CMakeLists.txt file but its still not compiling.

From:

```
if(WIN32)
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6 optimized GLFW_r32 debug GLFW_d32)
elif (UNIX)
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6 glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} GL rt dl)
else()
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6)
```

To:

```
if(WIN32)
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6 optimized GLFW_r32 debug GLFW_d32)
else()
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6 glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} GL rt dl)
```

And I've tried adding find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED) to the start of the file but still no success.

Heres my current CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (SuperBible6)

LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

if(WIN32)
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6 optimized GLFW_r32 debug GLFW_d32)
else()
set(COMMON_LIBS sb6 glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} GL rt dl)
endif()

IF(APPLE)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/System/Library/Frameworks)
  FIND_LIBRARY(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)
  FIND_LIBRARY(OpenGL_LIBRARY OpenGL)
  FIND_LIBRARY(IOKit_LIBRARY IOKit)
  MARK_AS_ADVANCED(COCOA_LIBRARY OpenGL_LIBRARY)
  SET(EXTRA_LIBS ${COCOA_LIBRARY} ${IOKit_LIBRARY} ${OpenGL_LIBRARY})
  SET(EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} /usr/local/lib/libglfw.a)
ENDIF(APPLE)

set(COMMON_LIBS ${COMMON_LIBS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})

add_library(sb6
src/sb6/sb6.cpp
src/sb6/sb6ktx.cpp
src/sb6/sb6object.cpp
src/sb6/sb6shader.cpp
src/sb6/gl3w.c
)

set(RUN_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(EXAMPLES
  alienrain
  basicfbo
  blendmatrix
  blinnphong
  bumpmapping
  clipdistance
  csflocking
  cubemapenv
  cubicbezier
  deferredshading
  depthclamp
  dispmap
  dof
  envmapsphere
  equirectangular
  fragcolorfrompos
  fragmentlist
  grass
  gsculling
  gslayered
  gsquads
  gstessellate
  hdrbloom
  hdrexposure
  hdrtonemap
  indexedcube
  instancedattribs
  julia
  ktxview
  linesmooth
  movingtri
  msaanative
  multidrawindirect
  multimaterial
  multiscissor
  multiviewport
  noise
  noperspective
  normalviewer
  objectexploder
  perf-readpixels
  perpixelgloss
  phonglighting
  polygonsmooth
  prefixsum
  prefixsum2d
  programinfo
  raytracer
  rimlight
  sampleshading
# sb6mrender
  shadowmapping
  shapedpoints
  simpleclear
  simpletexcoords
  simpletexture
  singlepoint
  singletri
  sparsetexture
  spinnycube
  springmass
  ssao
  starfield
  stereo
  subroutines
  tessellatedcube
  tessellatedgstri
  tessellatedtri
  tessmodes
  tesssubdivmodes
  toonshading
  tunnel
  wrapmodes
)

if (WIN32)
  set(EXAMPLES ${EXAMPLES} win32raw)
endif()

#if(UNIX)
#  add_executable(xraw src/xraw/xraw.c)
#  target_link_libraries(xraw GL X11 m)
#endif(UNIX)

foreach(EXAMPLE ${EXAMPLES})
  add_executable(${EXAMPLE} WIN32 src/${EXAMPLE}/${EXAMPLE}.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(${EXAMPLE} ${COMMON_LIBS})
  if(MSVC)
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/vs2010/VisualStudioUserFile.vcproj.user.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXAMPLE}.vcproj.user @ONLY)
    configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/vs2010/VisualStudioUserFile.vcxproj.user.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXAMPLE}.vcxproj.user @ONLY)
  endif(MSVC)
endforeach(EXAMPLE)

IF (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_LINUX")
ENDIF (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")

include_directories( include )
include_directories( extern/glfw-2.7.6/include )

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(debug ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(release ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Heres the errror I'm getting:

```
myron@myron-UX430UA:~/Desktop/sb6/sb6code-master$ make V=1
Scanning dependencies of target sb6
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6ktx.cpp.o
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6object.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/sb6shader.cpp.o
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/sb6.dir/src/sb6/gl3w.c.o
[  4%] Linking CXX static library lib/libsb6.a
[  4%] Built target sb6
Scanning dependencies of target wrapmodes
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o
[  6%] Linking CXX executable bin/wrapmodes
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o: in function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x8b): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xa1): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xb0): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xbf): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xd5): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o:wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0xf5): more undefined references to `glfwOpenWindowHint' follow
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/src/wrapmodes/wrapmodes.cpp.o: in function `sb6::application::run(sb6::application*)':
wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x133): undefined reference to `glfwGetDesktopMode'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x18b): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x1e9): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x25b): undefined reference to `glfwSetMousePosCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x267): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseWheelCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x280): undefined reference to `glfwEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x289): undefined reference to `glfwDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x29a): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
/usr/bin/ld: wrapmodes.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb611application3runEPS0_]+0x3bc): undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/build.make:85: bin/wrapmodes] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/wrapmodes.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Edit: Ran "make V=1" although I can't see any additional info.

Comment: You should show the output of `make V=1`. As you can see, CMake swallows important information without it.

Comment: Way too broad.  You can't just link a GLFW2 codebase against GLFW3 and hope for the best, you have to do a proper port to the new API.  Not to mention fixing every single one of their shaders & associated code that attempt to use `layout(binding)` with `#version 410 core`.

Comment: Hmmm... So this a backwards compatibility issue you say. I'll try to work with the 7th edition example files then. I hope they are not too different from my version. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code and the cmake file to work with GLFW3. Now the project compiles and runs. I uploaded it to github here: https://github.com/mlioz/sb6code_fixed